# Power Meter current (for EV charging)

Tags: charging, electric-vehicle

I would like to charge an EV at 10, or even 15A through a GPO that has a power meter attached.

The meter states 5(45)A, and
Rated Current (Ib ) 5 A
Maximum Rated Current (Imax)    45 A

So, will a lengthy continuous draw of 10A be too much for the meter, or does the 45 A max mean that I could theoretically draw 45 A continuously without ill effects on the meter?[image]

Comment: Welcome! Photo or link to datasheet please.

Comment: DRS-201A. Unsure as a new user of I can post a photo yet

Comment: Yes you can. Click on edit, go to where you want the picture to appear and click on the image symbol. From there you can import it.

Comment: And there's a hyperlink button so you can add a link to the datasheet (not an ad page) for the meter.

Comment: There was a very similar question or answer recently, and I think the 5(45)A was most likely for an external CT. Otherwise it might be that the meter can tolerate (and retain accuracy for) brief peak currents of 45A.

Comment: Yes, I saw similar answer about CT, but couldn’t find anything about rated current. I understand if it’s referring to CT it is accurate down to 5A, but I’m still trying to work out what continuous current I can run through it. 
I’ve been slowly ramping up from 5A for over 24 hrs

Comment: CI. 1 Accuracy (EN61036) Direct measurement up to 45A Built-in shunt;6 digits register display Pulse output
Single Phase DIN Rail Meter DRS-201A

Accuracy Class 1
Reference Voltage ( Un) 230V AC
Operating Voltage 160-300V AC
Impulse Voltage 6KV 1.2μ S waveform
Rated Current (Ib ) 5 A
Maximum Rated Current (Imax) 45 A
Operating Current Range 0.4% Ib ~ Imax
Operating Frequency Range 50Hz± 10%
Internal Power Consumption < 2W/10VA
Operating Humidity range < 75%
Storage Humidity range < 95%
Operating Temperature range -10º C ~+50º C